# How to code sql query to eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel

select t2.AGENT_ID, First_Login ,last_logout from (select AGENT_ID, EVENT_TIME as First_Login 
    from `datamart_agent_details` 
    where `datamart_agent_details`.`GRP_DBID` in ('3') 
    and `EVENT_TIME` between '2018-03-18 00:00:00' and '2018-03-18 23:59:59' 
    and `EVENT` = 'LOGIN' 
    group by `agent_id` 
    order by event_time asc
     ) t1 left join (select AGENT_ID, EVENT_TIME as last_logout 
    from `datamart_agent_details` 
    where `datamart_agent_details`.`GRP_DBID` in ('3') 
    and `EVENT_TIME` between '2018-03-18 00:00:00' and '2018-03-18 23:59:59' 
    and `EVENT` = 'LOGOUT' 
    group by `agent_id` 
    order by event_time desc
     )t2  on t1.agent_id=t2.agent_id

please how i convert that in eloquent laravel

Comment: Have u tried [RAW Sql](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries)

Comment: Try http://convert.sql.to.eloquent.org

Answer (score 0):

Once try with this

```
$fromTempTable = DB::raw("(select AGENT_ID, EVENT_TIME as First_Login from datamart_agent_details where datamart_agent_details.GRP_DBID in ('3') and EVENT_TIME between '2018-03-18 00:00:00' and '2018-03-18 23:59:59' and EVENT = 'LOGIN' group by agent_id order by event_time asc as) t2");

$leftTempTable = DB::raw("(select AGENT_ID, EVENT_TIME as last_logout from datamart_agent_details where datamart_agent_details.GRP_DBID in ('3') and EVENT_TIME between '2018-03-18 00:00:00' and '2018-03-18 23:59:59' and EVENT = 'LOGOUT' group by agent_id order by event_time desc) t1");

DB::table($fromTempTable)
    ->select('t2.AGENT_ID', 'First_Login', 'last_logout')
    ->leftJoin($leftTempTable, 't1.agent_id', '=', 't2.agent_id') 
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can use this query in both model and controller. But standard is model so put in model.

Comment: $DataTable  = AgentLogin::whereIn('datamart_agent_details.GRP_DBID',$arraylist)
        

        ->whereBetween('EVENT_TIME', array($from, $to))


        

        ->getAllQuery()
        ->groupInterval($interval)        this is my controller

Comment: return $query

        ->leftJoin('cfg_agent','cfg_agent.LOGIN_ID','=','datamart_agent_details.AGENT_ID')   
       ->select('t2.AGENT_ID', 'First_Login', 'last_logout')
       ->leftJoin($leftTempTable, 't1.agent_id', '=', 't2.agent_id') 


and this is my return query